# Command runs manually successfully, but fails quietly in cronjob

Tags: cron

I'm running this as a cron job:

```
( export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin' && echo "$PATH" && wget "https://www.mahmansystems.com.au/WSDataFeed.asmx/DownLoad?CustomerCode=%2F&WithHeading=true&WithLongDescription=true&DataType=0" -O mahman_direct.zip ) && echo 'I reached the end' &>> /home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/output.txt
```

When I run in CLI as the cron user, it works fine.

Hitherto, I have only had two reasons for quietly failing cron jobs which is explained by the difference in user and path when running commands in CLI versus in cron, but this time, it doesn't seem to be either, since I tested the cmd in CLI as the cron user, and no permission errors where observed.

The wget does output/display some text describing the process of retrieving the file, but there is no interaction or input/response required by the user.

No errors were directed to output.txt.

What else could be wrong?

Have also tried `curl -sLo` alternative, in case.  It makes no difference.

Comment: What shell do you use interactively? What shell does your crontab use? If you're not sure of the second, add this as a cron entry: `echo "$SHELL" >/tmp/shell` and look at the result

Comment: @roaima according to `echo "$SHELL"`: my interactive shell is `/bin/bash`.  Cron shell is also `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea about the `%` sign behaviour in cron environment.

Escape as `\%` and it works.

Ref 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921266

Ref 2: [Cron gotchas](https://www.tiger-computing.co.uk/cron-gotchas/#:%7E:text=Percent%20signs&text=Surely%20all%20the%20strings%20in,what%27s%20going%20on%3F&text=with%20the%20rest%20of%20the,percents%20with%20a%20backslash%3A%20%5C%25%20).

Comment: Your published code doesn't have `%` in it

Comment: @roaima indeed - I will edit the original to reflect the presence of the `%` - I apologise as I didn't think it was relevant - and it was a security-sensitive component of that URL, so I removed it from the code that was given, thinking the URL itself surely would be irrelevant - alas, lesson learnt.

Answer (score 1):

My personal recommendation to avoid special characters such as `%` triggering unexpected scenarios is to put anything for `cron` other than absolutely trivial operations in a script. (Although I suppose that a single call to `wget` might reasonably be classed as trivial. Mmm.) Then call the script from `cron`.

Example, `/usr/local/etc/mahmansystems` (remember the `chmod +x`):

```
#!/bin/sh
wget 'https://...' &&
    echo 'I reached the end'
```

And then, as an example system-level `cron` entry:

```
0 * * * * www-data /usr/local/etc/mahmansystems >>& /home/myparadise/public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/output.txt
```

If you had several calls for URLs from `mahmansystems` you could even `case`…`esac` them in the same script, providing a (simple) parameter to identify which one to use.